# How can I make the CSS-hover animation to stay?

Tags: html, css, animation

Followed along [THIS](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/css-trick-animating-link-underlines/) short tutorial of how to animate an underline with CSS.

I want to use this in my nav-header which means that I want the active tab header to be underlined all the time. Do anyone have any suggestion of how? The final code looks like this:

```
h2 > a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

h2 > a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

text-decoration: underline; doesn't look good at all

Comment: You can't do this with a transition..only an animation be it keyframed or scripted

Comment: So, to clarify: You want it like the link given, but constant and without the need for an animation? Just remove that second rule, and take out the "transform" and "visibility" properties.

Comment: You'll have to figure out which link is the active link. Possibly by adding a class to it (maybe via server-side code, maybe via client-side code).

Comment: Adding a class to the tab currently being viewed as Ryan suggests is the best way to approach this

Comment: You can use js with `$("h2>a").mouseover(function(){ YOUR CODE });` Until you make a mouseleave/mouseout function, it will not change. You can also use jquery hover function, and many others... Here is a link http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I've created a fiddle with what I believe is what you want. Just give the active tab the class "active" http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/wsLu306f/

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/" class="underlined-example active link">Hover this link</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.active {
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.link:hover {
    color: #000;
}
.link:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.link:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
.permalink:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

**JS**

```
$("a").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("permalink");
    setInterval(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("link");
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: yes! the .permalink:berfore-part was exactly what I was looking for. Missed ':before' when I was trying myself. Thanks!